# Dividing second row by first per group

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have data in the following format:

```
name = c("john", "john", "jack", "jack", "jason", "jason")
time_to_run_100_meters_last_year_this_year = c(22.3, 22.1, 12.4, 12.3, 15.1, 15.6)

my_data = data.frame(name, time_to_run_100_meters_last_year_this_year)


   name time_to_run_100_meters_last_year_this_year
1  john                                       22.3
2  john                                       22.1
3  jack                                       12.4
4  jack                                       12.3
5 jason                                       15.1
6 jason                                       15.6
```

I want to find out how the percent change in time for each student. This would mean: (22.1/22.3, 12.3/12.4, 15.6/15.1).

I thought of the following way to solve this problem:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data = my_data %>% 
  arrange(name) %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()


id_1 =  my_data[which(my_data$id == 1), ]

id_2 =  my_data[which(my_data$id == 2), ]

division =  id_2$time_to_run_100_meters_last_year_this_year/id_1$time_to_run_100_meters_last_year_this_year

unique = unique(my_data$name)

final_data = data.frame(unique, division)
```

In the end, I think my idea worked:

```
> final_data
  unique  division
1   jack 0.9919355
2  jason 1.0331126
3   john 0.9910314
```

**My Question:** But are there better ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have exactly two observations per group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_by` and `summarize` in the package `dplyr`.

Use `lead` for the value behind the current row and use `na.omit` to ignore `NA` in the calculation.

```r
library(dplyr)

final_data <- 
  my_data %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(division = na.omit(lead(time_to_run_100_meters_last_year_this_year)/time_to_run_100_meters_last_year_this_year))

final_data
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  name  division
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 jack     0.992
2 jason    1.03 
3 john     0.991
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `first` and `last` from `dplyr` could be another option given that you have only two observations per name:

```r
library(dplyr)

my_data |> 
  group_by(name) |> 
  summarize(division = last(time_to_run_100_meters_last_year_this_year)/first(time_to_run_100_meters_last_year_this_year)) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  name  division
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 jack     0.992
2 jason    1.03 
3 john     0.991
```